# Validar que una fecha no pueda ser mayor que otra con jcalendar

Tags: java, java-8, jcalendar

**Le implemente este codigo en mi controlador, pero no me funciona.**
"CODIGO ACTUALIZADO FUNCIONANDO, es simples pero me cumple lo que requiero"

```
     private boolean validarFormulario() {
if (actoAcademicoVentana.gettDesde().getDate().after(actoAcademicoVentana.gettHasta().getDate())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La Fecha Desde no puede ser mayor que la Fecha Hasta");
            actoAcademicoVentana.gettDesde().requestFocusInWindow();
            return false;
        }
        if (actoAcademicoVentana.gettFechaLlamado().getDate().after(actoAcademicoVentana.gettDesde().getDate())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La Fecha Llamado no puede ser menor que la Fecha Desde");
            actoAcademicoVentana.gettFechaLlamado().requestFocusInWindow();
            actoAcademicoVentana.gettFechaLlamado().setDate(null);
            return false;
        }
        if (actoAcademicoVentana.gettFechaLlamado().getDate().before(actoAcademicoVentana.gettHasta().getDate())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La Fecha Desde no puede ser mayor que la Fecha Hasta");
            actoAcademicoVentana.gettFechaLlamado().requestFocusInWindow();
            actoAcademicoVentana.gettFechaLlamado().setDate(null);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: incluye la versión de java que va a ser usada por favor.

Comment: estoy utilizando java 8, eclipseIDE

Answer (score 1):

Ya que usas JCalendar te conviene setear la **fecha máxima seleccionable** y así imposibilitar que el usuario seleccione fechas mayores a la establecida. De la misma forma con fechas menores, por ejemplo que no se pueda seleccionar fechas anteriores a hoy.

Un pequeño ejemplo:

```
import com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JCalendarEj {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyJcalendar cal=new MyJcalendar();
        cal.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }  
}
class MyJcalendar extends JFrame{

    private JCalendar calendar;

    public MyJcalendar() {
        setTitle("Ventana con Calendario");
        setBounds(350, 200, 400, 300);
        calendar = new JCalendar();
        calendar.setWeekOfYearVisible(false);//quitar nro. de semana del año
        calendar.setMinSelectableDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());//anteriores a hoy no seleccionables
        Calendar fechaMax =new GregorianCalendar(2020, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 28);//fecha máxima de ejemplo
        calendar.setMaxSelectableDate(fechaMax.getTime());//seteamos fecha máxima seleccionable
        
        JPanel lamina=new JPanel();        
        lamina.add(calendar);
        add(lamina);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```